# R: catch message, return result (efficiently)

Tags: r

Consider the function:

```
hello_world <- function() {
  message("hello world")
  "goodbye world"
}
```

With the constraint of only being allowed to call the function once (e.g. it could be an expensive computation), how do I get the value from the function call *and* catch the message (for handling)? I'm thinking of caching the value in the environment of the `tryCatch()` call, but can't work out how to do it.

Here are two *non-examples*:

```
# example 1
tryCatch(
  hello_world(),
  message = function(x) {
    cat("the message is: ", x$message,  "\n")
  }
)

# example 2
tryCatch(
  hello_world(),
  message = function(x) {
    cat("the message is: ", x$message,  "\n")
    hello_world()
  }
)
```

Comment: Use `sink` to divert the message stream to a connection?

Comment: This doesn't give me an option of handling the message though. I've updated my question to try and be more explicit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example using `sink`:

```
messageHandler <- function(fun, ...) {
  zz <- textConnection("foo", "w", local = TRUE)
  sink(zz, type = "message")
  res <- fun(...)  
  sink(type = "message")
  close(zz)
  #handle messages
  list(res, messages = foo) 
}


messageHandler(hello_world)
#[[1]]
#[1] "goodbye world"
#
#$messages
#[1] "hello world"

hello_world2 <- function() {
  message("hello world")
  message("how are you")
  "goodbye world"
}
messageHandler(hello_world2)
#[[1]]
#[1] "goodbye world"
#
#$messages
#[1] "hello world" "how are you"
```

Note that this will also catch warnings and message from `stop`, i.e., everything sent to `stderr()`.

Comment: Thank you very much for this example Roland - I've learnt something new today :D However I'm not sure if you're correct about it handling warnings and errors too. I don't whether its acceptable to reply to my own question, so I've created a gist [here](https://gist.github.com/Mullefa/270a0aab05d1b9e16119) which hopefully illustrates what I mean.

Comment: I've never claimed that this function would handle errors. And I'm somewhat surprised that evaluation isn't stopped when an error occurs. Obviously you need to use `tryCatch` inside this to handle errors. Anyway, the task was to handle messages. And there might well be better solutions, although I don't see another possibility to not interrupt/repeat evaluation and handle messages.

Comment: Apologies if I misunderstood - I got a bit confused as you talked about catching stuff from `stop()`. Answer aside, do you have any idea what the output of `messageHandler(h)` in the gist is?! I've haven't come across the likes of it before :D

Comment: `res` does not exist, because an error (as a call to `stop`) occured. The error message is catched by `messageHandler`, but can't be returned since evaluation is stopped. You need to do separate error handling.

Comment: Note that you interrupt the handler with the error, so all messages continue to go to `sink`.